# Adding a filter helper method to Laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, eloquent-relationship

I'd like to add a method to my Laravel `Product` model which filters by `name` attr and returns a collection of all matching products, here's what I've got:

### Product.php

```
public function filterByName($query)
{
    return $this->where('name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->get();
}
```

### ProductController.php

```
$products = collect(new Product);
$products->filterByName($name);
```

What's the correct usage of this? Do I need to use a QueryFilter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you talking about scope?

```
public function scopeByName($query, $param)
{
    return $query->where('name','LIKE','%'.$param.'%');
}
```

and then

```
$products = Product::byName('xyz')->get();
```